# GWT - loading stylesheet by locale or user action

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to load an external stylesheet by setting locale or other user action?
I would like to change the style presentation based on a user input.

Comment: I think I found something I can put into JSNI at http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use JSNI and DOM methods to create  (and add to DOM) a new `<link>` tag:

```
private native void loadCSS (String cssHref) /*-{
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' +
        cssHref + '">');
}-*/;
```